# What happened to Moshe's Mateh (stick)

Tags: sources-mekorot, moshe-rabbeinu, va-eira, mishkan-tabernacle, shemot-exodus

I once heard that Moshe's stick was used as the middle pole that held the beams together in the Mishkan that miraculously bent twice (Rashi, Shabbos 98b).

Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: It was with the Aron

Comment: Tיhis article mentions it too, though provides no source:
http://www.tog.co.il/he/Article.aspx?id=632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a combination of Midrashim - one that says that Moshe's stick was previously Yaakov's, and the other that saying that this bolt was Yaakov's:

The [Yalkut Shimoni (168)](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/shemot.html) writes that Moshe's stick had quite some history. It originated with Adam's banishment from Gan Eden, and was used by the Avos, etc. It was Yaakov that took it to Mitzraim, though it ended up in Reuel's posession. Reuel (aka Yisro) buried it in his garden in Midian, and it stayed there until Moshe took it out.

> ותען צפורה את אביה לאמר הלא שמעת [אבי] כי אלקי העברים גדול ונורא הוא ומפליא להם בכל עת. הוא הציל אברהם מאור כשדים ואת יצחק מן החרב ואת יעקב מן המלאך בהאבקו עמו. וגם עם זה רבות עשה ויצלהו מיאור מצרים ומחרב פרעה גם מזה יכול למלטהו. וייטב הדבר בעיני רעואל ויעש כן כדבר בתו וישלח אל הבור לראות מה נעשה בו. ויראו והנה האיש חי ועומד על רגליו ומתחנן אל אלקי אבותיו. ויוציאוהו מן הבור ויגלחוהו וישנו את בגדי כלאו ויאכל לחם. ויהי האיש אל גנת רעואל אשר אחרי הבית. ויתפלל אל אלקיו אשר עשה אתו נפלאות רבות. ויהי בהתפללו ויבט בצדו והנה מטה ספיר מוצב ארצה והוא נטוע בתוך הגנה ויקרב אל המטה והנה חקוק בו שם ה' אלקים צבאות כתוב ומפורש על המטה ויקרא בו ויתלשהו כהתלש עץ יער מסבכו ויהי למטה בכפו. הוא המטה הנברא בתבל מפעלות אלקים אחרי בוראו שמים וארץ וכל צבאם ימים ונהרות וכל דגתם. ויהי בהגרש אדם מגן עדן ויקח את כל המטה בידו ויצא ויעבוד את האדמה אשר לוקח משם ויגיע המטה עד נח ויותר אל שם ואל תולדותיו עד הגעתו אל ידי אברהם העברי ויתן אברהם את כל אשר לו ליצחק גם את מטה האותיות ירוש ירש. ויהי כברוח יעקב פדנה ארם ויקחהו בידו ובבואו אל יצחק אביו בארה שבע נטוש לא נטשו וברדתו מצרימה לקחו בידו ויתנהו אל יוסף שכם אחד על אחיו כי באמצו לקחו יעקב מיד עשו אבי אדום. ויהי אחרי מות יוסף וישבו שרי מצרים בית יוסף ויגיע המטה אל יד רעואל המדיני ובעת צאתו ממצרים לקחו בידו ויטעהו בתוך גנתו. ויבחנו כל גבורי קיני לתלשו בבקשם לקחת צפורה בתו ולא יכלו וישאר בתוך הגן עד בוא אשר לו המשפט ויקחהו. ויהי כראות רעואל את המטה בידו ויתמה על ככה ויתן רעואל צפורה בתו למשה.

The Daas Zekeinim Mibaalei Tosafos writes (Shemos 25:5) quotes a Midrash that the middle bolt was originally יעקב's staff.

> ועוד איתא במדרש שהבריח התיכון היה ממקלו של יעקב כד"א כי במקלי עברתי את הירדן הזה והביאו למצרים וכשיצאו העלוהו עמו:

Comment: Your answering  before or after

Comment: huh? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It seems the question is asking after Moshe

Answer (score 3):

**Opinion that Moshe and Aron had separate staffs.**

The Abarbenel Parshas B'shalch 17:1 writes that Moshe Rabbeinu was buried with his staff . This was done because Moshe was the greatest Navi and HaShem didn't want anyone else using this powerful tool.

Text: אברבנאל שמות פרק יז

ומפני שהיה המטה כלי האלהי יתברך לפעול הנפלאות נמסר לאדון הנביאים ואף יהושע תלמידו שקבל ממנו לא נשתמש במטה אלא בכידון שנא' (יהושע ח') ויאמר ה' אל יהושע נטה בכידון אשר בידך אל העי וענין זה שהמטה היה מורה על אדנות ויכולת וכענין שכתוב תקח בידך אשר תעשה בו את האותות. אבל הכידון הוא מנהג כל יוצא למלחמה וע"ז תבין ענין אמתי אומר אותו לך פה. והוא שהנה מטה אהרן הונח לפני ארון העדות למשמרת כמו שזכרה תורה ונגנז עם הארון וצנצנת המן וצלוחית שמן המשחה שהכל גנז יאשיהו המלך כאשר מצא חלקיהו הכהן הגדול את ספר התורה בהיכל ה' **אבל מטה משה לא ידענו מה היה לו ולא נזכר בשום מקום לא בכתובים ולא בדברי חכמינו זכרונם לברכה מה נעשה ממנו ומפני זה יחוייב שנאמר שכאשר עלה משה רבינו אל הר העברים למות שם הוליך מטה האלהים בידו ונקבר המטה עמו כי לא רצה יתברך שישתמש עוד בו בן אדם.** כי כמו שבמעלת הנבואה ובכל האותות והמופתים לא קם נביא עוד בישראל כמשה כן בכלי המיוחד לו לא נשתמש בו עוד אדם.

**Opinion that they used the same  staff.**

The staff was eventually was put away with the Aron Hakodesh. See Masheches Yoma 52b :

התניא משנגנז ארון נגנזה עמו צנצנת המן וצלוחית שמן המשחה **ומקלו של אהרן**

Comment: I am answering the title question,since I do not have a source for the middle pole.